# Content Import, Error

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2013

I am importing a package and getting following error

> Unable to save Process definition (tcm:0-0-0).]Name must be unique for items of type: Workflow Process definition within this Publication and its BluePrint context

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to save an element of the same name and location (webdav path) in a parent publication and it already exists in a child publication.  The item physically cannot saved (imported) because of the naming conflict in one of the child publications.

I'd check the content porter log to find out the actual item in question and review whether it should be removed in the child and introduced into your parent publication via content porting.

Answer (score 2):

Fully agree with Mr. Winter, but in case of Process Definitions, also check that in your Process Definitions list the Definition to be imported doesn't already exist for all Publications. If that is the case, then the best thing to do is to rename either the existing Definition or the Definition to be imported.

In any case, I would always exclude workflow from Content Porting and do this manually.

Comment: I have suggested to exclude workflows from all children publications, let see  if it works.